# htaccess redirection loop issue

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I have a static website that has several html pages. In order to not hide `.html` extensions from url, we have following rules in htaccess for each url:

```
RewriteRule ^website-development$               website-development.html
```

This works fine in that if you open `site.com/website-development`, it actually opens the `website-development.html` file but in url it does not show the .html extension.

Now, we need to redirect(or hide) `.html` urls to their corresponding urls without .html e.g. if someone opens `site.com/website-development.html` in their browser, the url should be shown as `site.com/website-development`.
To do this, I added following rule:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R]
```

But doing this results in indefinite redirection and so the browser just keeps redirecting and never renders the actual page. Can you please suggest how I can redirect both `site.com/website-development` and `site.com/website-development.html` to `site.com/website-development` (which actually is an html file - website-development.html ). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed, this rule will cause a redirect loop:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R]
```

It is due to the fact your `REQUEST_URI` is adding and removing `.html` in 2 different rules and `mod_rewrite` runs in a loop.

You can use this rule instead based on a `RewriteCond` that uses `THE_REQUEST`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it once.

Comment: It worked exactly as required and solved my problem. Thanks a lot :) . I will read more about `RewriteCond` and `THE_REQUEST` to gain more understanding. Also, I have read at some places to not use `R=301` while I am doing testing, is that right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. While testing keep it `R=302` or just `R` to avoid browser caching issues.